# Homotopy groups for homogeneous spaces $SU(2n)/Sp(n)$ and $SU(2n)/SO(2n)$

Tags: homotopy-theory, homogeneous-spaces

I would need to know $\pi_4$ and $\pi_5$ for $SU(2n)/Sp(n)$ and $SU(2n)/SO(2n)$ with $n\geq2$. The case of $SU(4)/Sp(2)$ is most important to me. I tried to search the literature but haven't been able to find the answer. Any hint or link to a good source would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Arunas Liulevicius wrote a paper about homotopy groups of Stieffel manifolds, I believe, probably sometime in the early 1960s. I can't promise that this is in there, but its the first place I'd start looking, because a forward search from that paper ought to locate something.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for the reference, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $SU(4) = Spin(6)$ and $Sp(2) = Spin(5)$ where $Spin(m)$ is the double cover of $SO(m)$. So

$$\frac{SU(4)}{Sp(2)} = \frac{Spin(6)}{Spin(5)} = \frac{SO(6)}{SO(5)} = S^5.$$

So $\pi_4(SU(4)/Sp(2)) = 0$ and $\pi_5(SU(4)/Sp(2)) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Of course! I was aware of the local isomorphisms $SU(4)\sim SO(6)$ and $Sp(4)\sim SO(5)$, but wasn't sure about the global structure. Thanks, this is very useful!